# »Das schönste, das du sein kannst, ist/bist du selbst.«

Tags: inflection, grammatical-person

I am not a native speaker of German, and so would like to verify if the following sentence is correct:

> Das schönste, das du sein kannst, ist du selbst.

In particular, I am not sure about the *ist*. In my opinion, the subject of the sentence is *das schönste, das du sein kannst*, and **not** *du,* and so the verb should be *ist,* not *bist.* However, my wife (who is a native speaker) feels that the verb must be *bist.*

Also, the English meaning I am trying to achieve is something similar to:

> The most beautiful thing you can be, is yourself.

and **not**:

> The most beautiful thing you can be, are you (yourself).

Comment: Research has been conducted on which of these sentences is grammatical in German, and why. Here are two references:


[http://babel.ucsc.edu/Jorge/ito_mester.html][1]
[Heck & Cuartero (2008)][2]


  [1]: http://babel.ucsc.edu/Jorge/ito_mester.html
  [2]: http://www.uni-leipzig.de/~asw/lab/lab87/LAB87_heck_cuartero.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for the subject …

Ignoring the relative clauses for the moment, you can (somewhat) say

> Du bist das Schönste.
>   Das Schönste bist du
>   Das Schönste ist: Du

Case one and two are basically the same sentence but case two makes use of the flexible placement of SPO in German. And all three sentences have valid grammar (although I have placed the colon in example three because my mind *wants* to say *bist* (*). The colon eases that desire a bit.)

In (1) and (2), the subject is *du*, thus the predicate is *bist*.
In (3), the subject is *das Schönste* (note that *Duden* says *Adjektive in substantivischem Gebrauch werden im Allgemeinen groß geschrieben*)

And a native German writer would probably evade the *bist*/*ist* dilemma by using a construct with *man* — like

> Das Schönste, was man sein kann, ist: Man selbst.

which would (in this case) not even be an evasion, but rather closer to what the original sentence wanted to express — Assumed it was not used to address someone directly, but rather anyone.

(*) Note that if you say … *something is something* … it is perfectly valid to exchange the *somethings* (i.e. subject and object) in any language … But example (3) just sounds clumsy in native ears — Even if it is perfect German.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I indeed decided to rephrase the sentence.

Comment: I stumbled over *search the subject* when editing. I want to replace it by *search for the subject* or *searching for the subject* but I don’t know what you want to convey so I left it.

Comment: I was thinking about something like *Cherchez la femme* when I thought about the heading... Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5):

*Duden* Volume 9 *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* suggests a simple test to identify the subject and the predicative in such sentences: Replace the linking verb (e.g. *sein*) with *gelten als* or *bezeichnet werden als.* The part that follows the conjunction *als* is the predicative (not the subject).

The example given in the question

> Das Schönste, das du sein kannst, ist/bist du selbst.

or its counterpart

> Du selbst ist/bist das Schönste, das du sein kannst.

can be replaced with

> **Als das Schönste,** das du sein kannst, giltst du selbst.
>
> **Als das Schönste,** das du sein kannst, kannst du selbst bezeichnet werden.

and

> Du selbst giltst **als das Schönste,** das du sein kannst.
>
> Du selbst kannst **als das Schönste,** das du sein kannst, bezeichnet werden.

Thus, *das Schönste* is the predicative (not the subject). Therefore, the correct sentences are:

> Das Schönste, das du sein kannst, bist du selbst.
>
> Du selbst bist das Schönste, das du sein kannst.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for the Duden link. However, I have the feeling that the "bist" version loses some of the meaning I want to convey. The predicate "du selbst sein" has meaning beyond the mere meaning of the words. Everybody is himself, but "du selbst sein" actually requires an effort. I do not want to say that "du" is "das Schönste", but that being "du selbst" is. I was trying to do that by taking a sentence like "Das Schönste [...] ist Feuermann." and replacing "Feuermann" with "du selbst". I realise now that I am then actually replacing the subject. I decided to rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

In German, the common phrase for [individuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individuation#In_Jungian_psychology) is [`Sei du selbst!`](https://www.google.de/search?q=sei%20du%20selbst), meaning that you should allow yourself to explore and develop who you truly are, instead of adapting to the expectations of who your surroundings think you should be.

Taking this phrase, the obvious corresponding construction is:

> Das Schönste, das du sein kannst, bist du selbst.

This will be understood by all native speakers of German to mean that your true self will be more beautiful than any [false and defensive facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_self_and_false_self).